# Generate Download URL After Successful Upload

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have successfully uploaded files to Firebase's storage via Google Cloud Storage through JS! What I noticed is that unlike files uploaded directly, the files uploaded through Google Cloud only have a Storage Location URL, which isn't a full URL, which means it cannot be read! I'm wondering if there is a way to generate a full URL on upload for the "Download URL" part of Firebase's actual storage.

[image]

Code being used:

```
    var filename = image.substring(image.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
    var gcs = gcloud.storage();
     var bucket = gcs.bucket('bucket-name-here.appspot.com');

     request(image).pipe(bucket.file('photos/' + filename).createWriteStream(
     {metadata: {contentType: 'image/jpeg'}}))
      .on('error', function(err) {})
    .on('finish', function() {



     console.log(imagealt);    


  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the GCloud client, you want to use [`getSignedUrl()`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.36.0/storage/file?method=getSignedUrl) to download the file, like so:

```
bucket.file('photos/' + filename).getSignedUrl({
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-17-2025'
}, function(err, url) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  // The file is now available to read from this URL.
  request(url, function(err, resp) {
    // resp.statusCode = 200
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you Mike! How do I combine it with createWriteStream or should it a code on it's own?

Comment: Within the `on('finish', function() {/* make the call to get the download URL */});` is a likely place, since it's uploaded properly at that point.

Comment: Are you a star or are you a star! Thank you very much :) The link still doesn't show up in Firebase's storage but it returns a working google cloud URL!

Comment: Not a problem. The link doesn't show up because it's actually creating a different URL--these ones expire after a certain amount of time, so they're slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

a) Create a download url through the firebase console

[image: create new download link]

b) if you attempt to get the downloadurl programmatically from a firebase client, one will be created on the fly for you.

Comment: Hey, thank you! The first one just creates a token? It isn't a full URL :( The second one sounds about right, how do I go about it?

Comment: the first one should create a "full url"  creating a token is what makes that possible.  What do you see that suggests that its not a download url and only the token?

Comment: the second one requires you use the firebase storage sdk.  See the [getting started guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) for more info.