# How to get generated thumbnail URL with after generating thumbnail in firebase cloudfunctions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase cloud function example https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail to generate thumbnails. But here, it didn't mention how to get a public URL of generated thumbnail in node JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to generate a download URL for the file (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824361/generate-download-url-after-successful-upload)) and can then download the file in the browser through the Firebase SDK (see [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url)).

Answer (score 0):

The last line of that firebase sample function actually writes both the full size image url and the _thumb url to the DB under /images/. Which you could grab in your app....

(if you're using firebase db, that is....)

```
    // Add the URLs to the Database
      return admin.database().ref('images').push({path: fileUrl, thumbnail: 
      thumbFileUrl});
      }).then(() => console.log('Thumbnail URLs saved to database.'));
```